# Problem instantiating a class in a scriptlet

Tags: jsp, netbeans

When I want to instantiate a class or use a static class method, I get an error on the web page. Here I show you what happens:

I have created this super simple class to show the problem:

```
package CalculosMatematicos;

public class calculos {
    
    public static int resultado;
    
    public static int metodoSuma(int num1, int num2){
        
        resultado = num1 + num2;
        return resultado;
    }
    
    public static int metodoResta(int num1, int num2){
        
        resultado = num1 - num2;
        return resultado;
    }
    
    public static int metodoMultiplicar(int num1, int num2){
        
        resultado = num1 * num2;
        return resultado;
    }
    
    public static int metodoDividirf(int num1, int num2){
        
        resultado = num1 / num2;
        return resultado;
    }
    
}
```

In the JSP I wrote:

```html
<%@page import="CalculosMatematicos.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        La suma de 7 + 5 es: <%= calculos.metodoSuma(7,5)%>
    </body>
</html>
```

The error is this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQDCF.png]

Comment: You should import java package like this `<%@page import="CalculosMatematicos.*"%>` .What's this `contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"` ? isn't that should be `<%@ page language="java"  contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"  %>` ?

Comment: I wrote <%@page import="CalculosMatematicos.*"%> but the error is the same. I wrote that because I saw in a tutorial that the teacher writes all that line.

Answer (score 0):

The class itself should be static otherwise you have to create a new object of type calculos

to give a little more clarification from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-class-in-java/

```
 // Static nested class 
    public static class NestedStaticClass { 


    // Only static members of Outer class 
    // is directly accessible in nested 
    // static class 
    public void printMessage() 
    { 

        // Try making 'message' a non-static 
        // variable, there will be compiler error 
        System.out.println( 
            "Message from nested static class: "
            + msg); 
    } 
}
```

So your class should be static because you have not instantiated it.
So either make the main class a static or instantiate the non-static class prior to use.

```
package CalculosMatematicos;

public static class calculos {
    
    public static int resultado;
    
    public static int metodoSuma(int num1, int num2){
        
        resultado = num1 + num2;
        return resultado;
    }
    
    public static int metodoResta(int num1, int num2){
        
        resultado = num1 - num2;
        return resultado;
    }
    
    public static int metodoMultiplicar(int num1, int num2){
        
        resultado = num1 * num2;
        return resultado;
    }
    
    public static int metodoDividirf(int num1, int num2){
        
        resultado = num1 / num2;
        return resultado;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: The name of the class is "calculos" and is static.

Comment: public class calculos
shouldn't that be 
public static class calculos?